# raspberry pi 4 4gb vs 8gb

Tags: raspberry-pi-os

I actually have a project to do which involves image processing from raspberry pi camera module through live video, it involves training of datasets and also includes some external sensors and modules like ultrasonice sensor and gps module. The code will be written in python using pycharm IDE So i wanted to ask which variant should i go for? 4gb one or 8gb and why? because i don’t want it to crash my code or to hang the whole system and also i’m a bit short on budget too please let me know, any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: Shopping requests are explicitly off-topic per the site's FAQ.

Comment: please refer to the explaination i’m actually asking about which one is better the one with 4gb ram or 8gb i described my work type too !! @Steve Robillard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should go for the most RAM you can afford, the 8gb has a significant performance advantage over the 4gb in my experience. I would also recommend using an SSD with an appropriate usb3 to sata adapter rather than an sd card as your boot device.